# Invalid object name when iterating over all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to iterate over all the tables with a given schema name and make a copy in the same db with another given schema.

This is the script I am using:

```
use DoctorWho
declare @sql_query as nvarchar(max)
select @sql_query = concat('insert into doctor_generated.' , table_name , ' select * from ' , table_name , ';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
WHERE table_schema LIKE 'dbo%';
exec (@sql_query);
```

However this throws an error:

> Invalid object name 'doctor_generated.tblEpisodeEnemy

Upon searching this error, I've refreshed the local cache & made sure I am using the correct db.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: The error appears to be telling you the problem, you don't have a table called `tblEpisodeEnemy` on the schema `doctor_generated`. This makes even more sense when you specifically have the clause `WHERE table_schema LIKE 'dbo%'`. `dbo` <> `doctor_generated`.

Comment: Also, that query will assign one arbitrary row to your variable `@sql_query`; is that your intent? I doubt you only have *one* table on your schema `dbo` (or schemas start with `dbo`.)

Comment: I am trying to insert tblEpisodeEnemy from dbo schema into doctor_generated.
Here are the tables from my db : https://imgur.com/a/ShEQRs4 . Isn't this one of the ways to do this?

Comment: To re-state Larnu's point, you aren't iterating over anything here.

Comment: But you aren't trying to `INSERT` into a table called `dbo.tblEpisodeEnemy`, @lina9 , you're said it's called `doctor_generated.tblEpisodeEnemy`. I think you need to elaborate on the problem you are *actually* trying to solve here.

Comment: So, are you just trying to duplicate all your tables on a new schema? Do those tables already exist, or are you looking to create and duplicate the data?

Comment: ok, maybe I didnt explain correctly. As you can see from my screenshot, I have all those tables in DoctorWho that I am trying to make a copy of using a different schema name(their current schema name is dbo, but I am trying to have them as doctor_generated). I am trying to iterate over all the tables using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables inside the @sql_query variable and then using exec to execute. Is there any other way of approaching this without having to rely on a cursor?

Comment: @Larnu , they already exist. I am just trying to duplicate the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* what you actually want is something like this. Firstly use string aggregation for your dynamic statement; I *assume* you are on a fully supported version of SQL Server as you don't state you aren't. Next use `QUOTENAME` to properly quote your objects and avoid injection.

Then you can execute your dynamic statement:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(N'SELECT * INTO doctor_generated.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N';',@CRLF)
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE s.[name] = N'dbo';

--PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. It works, but why do we have to use CRLF in string aggregation? Would it be the same without CRLF?

Comment: You try debugging a single line of SQL that is thousands of characters long, @lina9 . ;) Formatting is important, even in dynamic statements.